# AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'attr'

Tags: python, object, inheritance

The following code runs nicely with no error:

```
class A(object):
  pass

a = A()
a.attr = True
```

Running the following code:

```
o = object()
o.attr = True
```

raises the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-9fd7259047d0> in <module>()
      1 o = object()
----> 2 o.attr = True

AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'attr'
```

Why? Class `A` inherited from `object`, so why do I get an error when I create an object from class `object`?

Comment: This isn't weird behavior at all, subclasses can support additional attributes that the base class does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_object.asp):

> The object() function returns an empty object.
>
> You cannot add new properties or methods to this object.

Running a quick type comparison:

```
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> type(o)
<class 'object'>
```

shows that `a` and `o` are fundamentally different.

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object):

> Note object does not have a **dict**, so you can’t assign arbitrary attributes to an instance of the object class.

Comment: Thanks for great info! Weird behavior by Python though.